# Firestore can read through collection('users') but not doc('users/{id}')

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, react-native-firebase

I'm using `@react-native-firebase/firestore`

I must be thinking through collections or documents the wrong way, but I would expect the below security rules to stop me from getting docs through `onSnapshot` if they are denied when directly getting them through `doc` but that isn't the case

```js
// I get permission denied when doing this
firestore().doc('users/KRImYj0Lrmv00P9KRAuJ').get()

// I do not get permission denied when doing this and can access the document I can't get above
firestore().collection('users').onSnapshot()
```

Security Rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read: if resource.data.is_deleted == false
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### UPDATE FULL CODE

```js
// FIRST
try {
  await firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .where('is_deleted', '==', true)
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach((s) => {
          console.log('User', s.data())
        })
      }
    })
}
catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
// SECOND
try {
  const docs = await firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .where('is_deleted', '==', true)
    .get()

  console.log(docs)
}
catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

The first one returns the snapshots and I can log the docs

```
FIRST LOGS

User {"fname": "Steve", "is_deleted": true, "lname": "Kaspar", "name": "Steven Kaspar", "name_change_count": 2}
User {"fname": "Brian", "is_deleted": true, "lname": "Fitz"}


SECOND LOGS

[Error: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.]
```

Comment: I'm confused - are you saying that the `get()` is not allowed, but the `onSnapshot()` is allowed with these rules?  Please edit the question to be clear what exactly is working or not.

Comment: @DougStevenson - sorry, the opposite. I can't `get()` but I can get it through `onSnapshot()`

Comment: I would not expect the second query to work at all, because it lacks a filter for is_deleted==false.  Please be certain that your rules are saved and that your queries are correct.  Also, if you have other rules, be sure to show them here.

Comment: @DougStevenson - that's what I was expecting. That's the entire rule set, so I have no idea what to try next. Just keep breaking and retrying until it works I guess haha

Comment: Agreed with Doug here: this seems weird. Some steps to help debug: 1) Can you try to do a `get()` instead of `onSnapshot()` on the collection too? 2) Can you edit to show how you handle the `onSnapshot()`? I'm specifically curious if/how you're handling errors.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - I appreciate the help. Would love to use Firebase in an upcoming app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that in the `onSnapshot` case the results are coming from the local cache, which was populated before you disallowed the read operation.

That is the normal behavior for `onSnapshot`: if the requested documents are in the cache, it fires with those immediately, and then may fire again if the documents on the server are different. And since the security rules are only enforced on the server, that first callback will always happen if there's data in the cache.

A `get()` call on the other hand *immediately* tries to get the document from the server. And that in your case rejects the read operation. You could validate this by doing `get({ source: 'cache' })`, which will read the documents from the cache, and likely will succeed for the same reason that `onSnapshot` does.

I recommend clearing the local cache by uninstalling and reinstalling the app, so that it won't contain the documents that the user (now) doesn't have rights to anymore.

Comment: I tried erasing the contents of the simulator yesterday thinking that might be the case but it didn’t seem to do anything. I’m going to try resetting the device again today and running again to see if changes have taken effect. I’m with you - I think caching has got to be the issue at some level

Comment: Ok, so I reset the device and did --reset-cache on the react-native cache. Now, the `onSnapshot` never returns any results (snapshot is null). I guess that's the expected behavior? I would expect that to fail the same way with a permissions error I guess but maybe there is a reason it quietly fails?

Comment: Good to hear you got rid of the cache. Intermittent loss of internet connections is expected behavior, so not treated as an error condition for `onSnapshot`. You can check on any snapshots your listener get whether they came from the server (or at least are guaranteed to be in-sync with the server), which is typically what you'll use to show some indicator to the user on the status of their data.