# Firestore: subcollection pretends to be empty

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

friends. Really need your help on this one. I've developed an iOS app that uses Firestore database and Storage. Everything works as intended. The thing I'm stuck with is propagating changes using Firebase Admin SDK or Cloud Functions. In short, 'users' collection is selectively invisible to my queries.

My Firestore DB structure:

- 'users' (collection, level 1)  -> userID (doc) -> 'User_Data' (collection) -> 'UserData' (doc)
- 'Global_Data' (collection, level 1) -> 'GlobalData' (doc)

[image]

[image]

I can get the contents of any document/collection under 'users' -> 'uid'-> ... , except under 'users' level 1 collection.

For example I can see/mofidy the data in collection/document:

- users -> abC4dRefemSow3npM5uG1L2BsTV2 -> User_Data
- users ->
  abC4dRefemSow3npM5uG1L2BsTV2 -> User_Data -> UserData
- Global_Data ->
  GlobalData
- Global_Data

But not

- users
- users ->  abC4dRefemSow3npM5uG1L2BsTV2

When I try to see how many documents are in 'users' collection directly, it returns 0.
When I try to access any user like so, users -> abC4dRefemSow3npM5uG1L2BsTV2, it says that the document doesn't exist. I cannot fathom why.

And **the reason I need this to work** is because I need a function that will loop through all my users and be able to modify a specific document for each of them.

**For example**, for each user in users collection, add a field "X" in "User_Data -> UserData" document.
But, if I try to get the number of documents under users, it returns without looping through any of them.

Tried both deploying Cloud Function and using Firebase Admin SDK on my local machine with the same results. No errors. 'users' are invisible.

**index.js (JavaScript):**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require("./key.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const db = admin.firestore(); //with no parameter, using default database


// this works
const userId = 'abC4dRefemSow3npM5uG1L2BsTV2'; //user id

db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('User_Data').get()
.then((querySnapshot) => {
  console.log("Number of documents retrieved:", querySnapshot.size);

  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(`${doc.id} =>`, doc.data());
  });

  if (querySnapshot.empty) {
    console.log("No documents found in 'users' collection.");
  }
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error("Error getting documents: ", error);
})
```

When I change this line,

```
db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('User_Data').get()
```

to this

```
db.collection('users').get()
```

It no longer prints any results. Like an empty collection. No errors.

I've changed my Firestore security rules (for testing):

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I created a service account, got a json key, and gave Owner's permissions to it. This is a screenshot of my IAM admin page with permissions.
[image]

Any help is much appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: can you try with a single document  `db.collection('users').doc(userId).get()`,  share your db structure also check this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60979697/firestore-can-read-through-collectionusers-but-not-docusers-id),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76361173/why-does-collection-get-return-empty-results-although-i-do-have-data-in-fir),[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485960/getting-an-empty-query-when-querying-documents-on-firebase-firestore)

Comment: db.collection('users').doc(userId).get() prints: "No such document in 'users' collection." 
db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('User_Data').get(),prints the contents just fine. 

Thank you for the links, but I wasn't able to find the solution there. I tried using a collectionGroup on 'users' but it also doesn't return anything.
Photos of my db structure are added.

Comment: Have a look at this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) & stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495026/is-there-a-method-to-iterate-through-all-documents-in-a-collection-in-firestore)

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible that the document might have been deleted.Deleting a document does not delete its subcollections!

As mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#delete_documents)

> When you delete a document, Cloud Firestore does not automatically delete the documents within its subcollections. You can still access the subcollection documents by reference. For example, you can access the document at path `/mycoll/mydoc/mysubcoll/mysubdoc` even if you delete the ancestor document at `/mycoll/mydoc`.

Non-existent ancestor documents appear in the console, but they do not
appear in query results and snapshots.

Hence, You might be able to see/modify the data in collection/document:

```
users -> abC4dRefemSow3npM5uG1L2BsTV2 -> User_Data
users -> abC4dRefemSow3npM5uG1L2BsTV2 -> User_Data -> UserData
Global_Data -> GlobalData
Global_Data
```

But not

```
users
users -> abC4dRefemSow3npM5uG1L2BsTV2
```

If you want to delete a document and all the documents within its subcollections, you must do so manually. For more information, see [Delete Collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections).

Comment: Thank you. Turned out, I had to use collectionGroup, and do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I needed using **collectionGroup**. It is apparently what is needed to make deeper-level queries.

To make it work, I also had to create an **index** for at least two fields: in my case isDeleted and editedAt.

When I run the collectionGroup query, I run it not on top level 'users' collection, but on the **bottom level** 'User_Data' collection.

Also, in my query I had to **include both fields** (isDeleted and editedAt), that I added to the composite index earlier.

```
db.collectionGroup('User_Data').where('isDeleted', '==', true).where('editedAt', '<', retensionEndDate).get()
```

[This](https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries/) article helped.